# True or false identity?

Tags: number-theory, summation

I found the logo from The Eighth Congress of Romanian Mathematicians. I think this is the von Mangoldt summatory function and with a simple computation, using [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function), I obtained $83$. Am I wrong or how can the following be true?$$ \sum_{i=1929}^{2015}\Lambda(i)=8
$$

Comment: Apparently their $\Lambda$ is not the von Mangoldt function.

Comment: The Seventh congress used $\chi$ as the function and had an upper limit of 2011.  The Sixth was in 2007, I don't recall whether this "joke" was used there.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps

$$\Lambda(i)=
\begin{cases}
1\quad\text{if a Congress was held in year }i\\
0\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 8):

Note the indices of summation look a lot like years; $\Lambda : \mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$ is the function indicating whether that year had a Congress of Romanian Mathematicians.

Comment: Great minds think alike.... ;-)